# REStful API promise calling another promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise

I am refactoring my code using promises. I am running into a problem. I have two API routes. First one is api.js and the second is account.js. I also have 4 controllers(CommentController, ZoneController, ProfileController, AccountController) .

CommentController, ZoneController, and ProfileController share the same API route(api.js).

account.js uses AccountController. But AccountController's method uses ProfileController's method.

I ended up having Promise calling another Promise, but I am not returning data properly. It is leaving the server hanging. How can I return data when one Promise is calling another Promise?
Basically account.js is calling AccountController.js that has a method that calls ProfileController.js, but both AccountController and ProfileController are refactored to Promise. I am not getting data back. Please help.

```
AccountController.js

var ProfileController = require('./ProfileController');

module.exports = {

  currentUser: function(req) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      if (req.session == null) {
        reject({message: 'User not logged in'});
        return;
      }

      if (req.session.user == null) {
        reject({message: 'User not logged in'});
        return;
      }

      ProfileController.findById(req.session.user, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          reject({message: 'fail'});
          return;
        }
        resolve(result);
        return;
      });
    });
  }

ProfileController.js

  findById: function(id) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      Profile.findById(id, function(err, profile){
        if(err){
          reject(err);
          return;
        }
        resolve(profile);
        return;
      });
    })
  },

account.js 

router.get('/:action', function(req, res, next) {

  var action = req.params.action;

  if (action == 'logout') {
    req.session.reset();
    res.json({
      confirmation: 'success',
      message: 'Bye!'
    });
    return;
  }

  if (action == 'login') {
    res.json({
      confirmation: 'success',
      action: action
    });
    return;
  }

  if (action == 'currentuser') {
    AccountController.currentUser(req)
      .then(function(result){
        res.json({
          confirmation: 'success',
          user: result
        });
        return;
      })
      .catch(function(err){
        res.json({
          confirmation: 'fail',
          message: err.message
        });
        return;
      });

  }
});
```

Comment: Seems that your forgot to modify your `currentUser` function in `AccountController` to use your refactored `findById` function in `ProfileController`: you are passing a callback, although `findById` only expects a single `id` argument

Comment: also please include some test cases since we don't know what kind of output you would be expecting

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at my problem. Kermit solution solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should modify `AccountController.js`

```js
AccountController.js

var ProfileController = require('./ProfileController');

module.exports = {

  currentUser: function(req) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      if (req.session == null) {
        reject({message: 'User not logged in'});
        return;
      }

      if (req.session.user == null) {
        reject({message: 'User not logged in'});
        return;
      }

      ProfileController.findById(req.session.user).then(
      function (profile){
        resolve(profile);
      },function (err) {
        reject(err);
      });
  }
```

Comment: the first function is called when the resolve function of promise is running, the second function is called when the reject function of promise is running

Comment: aww.. it worked. Can you explain why your solution works? Thanks again.

Comment: @Kermit you can edit your answer instead of adding explanation in comment.

Comment: @CamoPac Note: this can be optimized further.

Comment: because the return value of  `findById` is a promise object but not call callback function,so you shouldn't use callback to receive result  and can call `then` function of promise object to receive result